# Vector Subtraction - Why does subtraction of two vectors give you a vector pointing from one to the other?

Tags: linear-algebra

Could someone explain in an intuitive way why subtracting two vectors (say, $B - A$) gives you vector from $A$ to $B$?

Comment: Do you understand why the sum of, vectors $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{BC}$ gives $\vec{AC}$ ?

Comment: If you are satisfied with parallelogram law then use parallelogram law to B-A , A.

Comment: @D.Dmitriy sorry - I do not. I'm very new to all this

Comment: Imho, one introductory chapter on vectors in a book will explain basics much better, than what is possible here. If you study vectors in a class, then use book(s) recommended by teacher. To properly answer your question, one should also know definition of the vector which you use (I know at least 3 different variations) and their corresponding definition of addition.

Comment: @D.Dmitriy this was helpful. I got a book and I think I get it. Thank you